# Check phone number and replace its value?

Tags: jquery, select, append

I have this kind of html select

```
<select name="countryCode" id="country" data-content='Your seleceted country code' data="required">
<option value="">Select your country code</option>
<option data-countryCode="DZ" value="+213">Algeria (+213)</option>
<option data-countryCode="DZ" value="+213">Algeria (+213)</option>
<option data-countryCode="AD" value="+376">Andorra (+376)</option>
<option data-countryCode="AO" value="+244">Angola (+244)</option>
</select>
```

And input of phone

```
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your mobile phone" data="required" id="phone" data-content='Your mobile phone'>
```

What I need is when user enter his country code, and enter mobile number, to check country code and append value of `#phone`, but the problem is on #phone user normally enters 0, I want to remove that 0 and append country code.

For now I have this

```
 $(function () {

    $('#phone').on('focusout', function () {
        var cc = $('select[name=countryCode]').val().replace(/^.*\(([\)]+)\).*$/, '$1');
        $(this).val(cc + $(this).val());
  });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove first char before append code.
so your jquery

```
$('#phone').on('focusout', function () {
         var f1 = $("#phone").val().charAt(0);
     var val=$("#phone").val();
     if(f1==0){
         $("#phone").val(val.substring(1, val.length));}
        var cc = $('select[name=countryCode]').val().replace(/^.*\(([\)]+)\).*$/, '$1');
             $(this).val(cc + $(this).val());
  });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/x7c7c/3/)